# Ancora e link no mesmo href sem perder efeito

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema, tenho um arquivo javascript que faz o scroll ficar suave quando clica em uma âncora, porém preciso que esse href contenha a âncora mas também contenha o link para quando estiver em outra página voltar para a que eu quero, ja tentei fazer algo como href="index.php#header" mas quando faço isso o efeito de scroll suave some, eu queria fazer quando ele estiver na página index.php ele ficar com o scroll suave na âncora e quando estiver em outra página ele servir como um link para a index.php.

```js
/****JAVASCRIPT **********/
jQuery.easing.jswing = jQuery.easing.swing;
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
    def: "easeOutQuad",
    swing: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e, f, a, h, g)
    },
    easeInQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * (f /= g) * f + a
    },
    easeOutQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * (f /= g) * (f - 2) + a
    },
    easeInOutQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * f * f + a
        }
        return -h / 2 * ((--f) * (f - 2) - 1) + a
    },
    easeInCubic: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * (f /= g) * f * f + a
    },
    easeOutCubic: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * ((f = f / g - 1) * f * f + 1) + a
    },
    easeInOutCubic: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * f * f * f + a
        }
        return h / 2 * ((f -= 2) * f * f + 2) + a
    },
    easeInQuart: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * (f /= g) * f * f * f + a
    },
    easeOutQuart: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * ((f = f / g - 1) * f * f * f - 1) + a
    },
    easeInOutQuart: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * f * f * f * f + a
        }
        return -h / 2 * ((f -= 2) * f * f * f - 2) + a
    },
    easeInQuint: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * (f /= g) * f * f * f * f + a
    },
    easeOutQuint: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * ((f = f / g - 1) * f * f * f * f + 1) + a
    },
    easeInOutQuint: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * f * f * f * f * f + a
        }
        return h / 2 * ((f -= 2) * f * f * f * f + 2) + a
    },
    easeInSine: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * Math.cos(f / g * (Math.PI / 2)) + h + a
    },
    easeOutSine: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * Math.sin(f / g * (Math.PI / 2)) + a
    },
    easeInOutSine: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h / 2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * f / g) - 1) + a
    },
    easeInExpo: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return (f == 0) ? a : h * Math.pow(2, 10 * (f / g - 1)) + a
    },
    easeOutExpo: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return (f == g) ? a + h : h * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * f / g) + 1) + a
    },
    easeInOutExpo: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if (f == 0) {
            return a
        }
        if (f == g) {
            return a + h
        }
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (f - 1)) + a
        }
        return h / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --f) + 2) + a
    },
    easeInCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * (Math.sqrt(1 - (f /= g) * f) - 1) + a
    },
    easeOutCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * Math.sqrt(1 - (f = f / g - 1) * f) + a
    },
    easeInOutCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return -h / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - f * f) - 1) + a
        }
        return h / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (f -= 2) * f) + 1) + a
    },
    easeInElastic: function(f, h, e, l, k) {
        var i = 1.70158;
        var j = 0;
        var g = l;
        if (h == 0) {
            return e
        }
        if ((h /= k) == 1) {
            return e + l
        }
        if (!j) {
            j = k * 0.3
        }
        if (g < Math.abs(l)) {
            g = l;
            var i = j / 4
        } else {
            var i = j / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(l / g)
        }
        return -(g * Math.pow(2, 10 * (h -= 1)) * Math.sin((h * k - i) * (2 * Math.PI) / j)) + e
    },
    easeOutElastic: function(f, h, e, l, k) {
        var i = 1.70158;
        var j = 0;
        var g = l;
        if (h == 0) {
            return e
        }
        if ((h /= k) == 1) {
            return e + l
        }
        if (!j) {
            j = k * 0.3
        }
        if (g < Math.abs(l)) {
            g = l;
            var i = j / 4
        } else {
            var i = j / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(l / g)
        }
        return g * Math.pow(2, -10 * h) * Math.sin((h * k - i) * (2 * Math.PI) / j) + l + e
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function(f, h, e, l, k) {
        var i = 1.70158;
        var j = 0;
        var g = l;
        if (h == 0) {
            return e
        }
        if ((h /= k / 2) == 2) {
            return e + l
        }
        if (!j) {
            j = k * (0.3 * 1.5)
        }
        if (g < Math.abs(l)) {
            g = l;
            var i = j / 4
        } else {
            var i = j / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(l / g)
        }
        if (h < 1) {
            return -0.5 * (g * Math.pow(2, 10 * (h -= 1)) * Math.sin((h * k - i) * (2 * Math.PI) / j)) + e
        }
        return g * Math.pow(2, -10 * (h -= 1)) * Math.sin((h * k - i) * (2 * Math.PI) / j) * 0.5 + l + e
    },
    easeInBack: function(e, f, a, i, h, g) {
        if (g == undefined) {
            g = 1.70158
        }
        return i * (f /= h) * f * ((g + 1) * f - g) + a
    },
    easeOutBack: function(e, f, a, i, h, g) {
        if (g == undefined) {
            g = 1.70158
        }
        return i * ((f = f / h - 1) * f * ((g + 1) * f + g) + 1) + a
    },
    easeInOutBack: function(e, f, a, i, h, g) {
        if (g == undefined) {
            g = 1.70158
        }
        if ((f /= h / 2) < 1) {
            return i / 2 * (f * f * (((g *= (1.525)) + 1) * f - g)) + a
        }
        return i / 2 * ((f -= 2) * f * (((g *= (1.525)) + 1) * f + g) + 2) + a
    },
    easeInBounce: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e, g - f, 0, h, g) + a
    },
    easeOutBounce: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g) < (1 / 2.75)) {
            return h * (7.5625 * f * f) + a
        } else {
            if (f < (2 / 2.75)) {
                return h * (7.5625 * (f -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * f + 0.75) + a
            } else {
                if (f < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
                    return h * (7.5625 * (f -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * f + 0.9375) + a
                } else {
                    return h * (7.5625 * (f -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * f + 0.984375) + a
                }
            }
        }
    },
    easeInOutBounce: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if (f < g / 2) {
            return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(e, f * 2, 0, h, g) * 0.5 + a
        }
        return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e, f * 2 - g, 0, h, g) * 0.5 + h * 0.5 + a
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- AQUI ESTÁ O HEADER QUE CONTÉM AS ÂNCORAS E OS HREF -->
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav  id='cabecalho' class='navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>

        <div class='navbar-header inDiv'>
           
            <a class='page-scroll' href='index.php#header'>
                <img id='logo' src='img/logo.png' width='300px' >
            </a>

            <!--Menu -->
            <div id='menu' class='navbar'>
                        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar menu' id='removeHover'>
                            <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                            <li class='hidden'>
                                <a href='#page-top'></a>
                            </li>
                             <li>
                                <a class='page-scroll' href='#sales'>Sales</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='page-scroll' href='#acquisition'>Acquisition</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='page-scroll' href='#letting'>Lettings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='page-scroll' href='#commercial'>Commercial</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Telefone e E-mail -->
    <div id='contato' class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
           <a  id='phone' href='tel:+4402079383777'><p  class='text'>+44 020 7938  3777</p></a>
           <a  id='mail2' href='mailto:info@lundinium.com'><p class='text'><strong>info@lundinium.com</strong></p></a>
</nav>
";

<!-- END HEADER -->

   <!--AQUI ESTÁ ONDE PRECISO CARREGAR QUANDO FOR CLICADO TANTO EM ANCORA QUANTO LINK COMUM -->
<header class="intro content-block" id="header" > 
       <div id="boxMobile" class="boxMobile">
            <button type="button" class="btnMobile" href="tel:+4402079383777">+44 020 7938 3777</button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btnMobile" href="mailto:info@lundinium.com">info@lundinium.com</button>
       </div>
        <div id='loadercab' class='loadercab' style='display:none;'></div>
        <div  id='fraB' style='width=100%;'>
            <section class="bottom">
                    <a id="scrollToContent" style='display:none;' href="#">
                        <img src="img/arrow_down.png">
                    </a>
            </section>
            <span id='frase' style='display: none;' class='ver'>Proactive Property People</span> <button style='display: ;' id='btnOpen' onclick='modalOpen();'><span style='padding-top: 5px;'>VALUATION</span><span>ENQUIRY</span><svg width='50' height='50' id='btnSvg'><circle style='margin-bottom: 31px;' cx='18' cy='18' r='18' stroke-width='0' fill='white' />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg> </button>
        </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples. Inclua o arquivo que contém a função do Scroll somente na index que é onde você quer o efeito, nas outras deixe apenas o comportamento nativo cuidar do trabalho (redirecionar para a âncora da página index).